# Segmentation Fault | Python | Cloud9

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, python-2.x, cloud9

Everyone!
So I am making a quick python text based game as an exercise while learning python. However my code which was running fine stopped functioning suddenly for no apparent reason. Around the WraithHunterStronghold() function which is a faction in game for whatever reason it leases a segmentation fault. Here's the code:

```
    if (option == "1"):
        if (PlayerIG.Gold >= 5000):
            os.system('clear')
            PlayerIG.WraithHunter = "Trans"
            PlayerIG.Gold-=5000
            print("You were given a potion called Hunter's Bane.")
            option = raw_input('')
            Explore()
```

Explore is another function that works fine. The Segfault happens right after the option = raw_input('') which I am simply using as a pause. When another place in the code tries to run the Explore() function no errors are raised. Only in this specific spot on the code does it lease this error. I am using Python 2 on Cloud9 https://ide.c9.io/mechanicalskeptic/legacy-of-eredaric-isles

Cloud9 acts as a Ubuntu VM so my OS in this case is whatever version of Ubuntu c9 uses.

The modules I am using are as follows: 
    os, sys, pickle, random, and re

I have tried this:
ulimit -s 2000 
somebody said that fixed their issue but for me it still continues.

Thanks for all your help everyone! I'm stumped as the SAME code was running 3 minutes ago. And I literally restarted the code and ran it again without editing it, and this happens.

Comment: Ghosts cannot hold your application, you must ensure that the app is kept by the system with another cycle.